# without knowing the structure of an xdoc, select elements whose immediate value is

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

UPDATE:
I totally oversimplified the question and led everyone astray with the wrong problem. Here is the *actual* problem: I'm trying to grab elements whose value matches a regex. I rewrote the question...

Given an XDocument where I don't know the structure, how do I select all elements that have a value matching a regex?

For example:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ var1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ var2 }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ var3 }}</td>
                <td>{{ var4 }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would get a result for html, body, table, tr, and four td elements. How can I select all elements that have a value that matches this regex and only return the td elements

```
private Regex _placeholderRegex = new Regex("({{.+?}})");

public string GetParsedDocument(...)
{
    var placeHolders = _template
        .Descendants()
        .Where(d => _placeholderRegex.IsMatch(d.Value));

    // more stuff
    return null;
}
```

I end up getting a result for every element that is an ancestor of the element(s) that I'm looking for...

So now that I think about it, I see that it's just looking at the entire contents of each element and selecting it if it contains a match anywhere in there. So I guess just need to find a way to narrow it.

Comment: I think you are looking for Text, not Value. (Note that it would be nice to *not* show HTML as an example of XML, but...)

Comment: I'm actually attempting to build a template parser for creating html emails. I've got the html doc parsed into an XDocument just for manipulation purposes, the XDoc is not publicly exposed. Also, Text doesn't seem to be an available property.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic [can't reproduce the problem](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GGkYIf) (only 2 elements returned as expected)

Comment: Ack... ok so that's my fault. i tried to simplify the problem and ended up obscuring it. The truth is that I'm using a regex to do the match. I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible way :

```
var placeHolders = from d in mydoc.Descendants()
                   where d.DescendantNodes()
                          .OfType<XText>()
                          .Any(o => o.Parent == d && _placeholderRegex.IsMatch(o.Value))
                   select d;
```

Above codes works by checking if any text node, that is direct child of current node `d` (`Parent == d`), has value match the regex pattern.

Here is a working example for [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5VbQm2) :

```
var xml = @"<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ var1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ var2 }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ var3 }}</td>
                <td>{{ var4 }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>";
var mydoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var _placeholderRegex = new Regex("({{.+?}})");
var placeHolders = from d in mydoc.Descendants()
                   where d.DescendantNodes()
                          .OfType<XText>()
                          .Any(o => o.Parent == d && _placeholderRegex.IsMatch(o.Value))
                   select d;
foreach (var placeHolder in placeHolders)
{
    Console.WriteLine(placeHolder.Value);
}
```

**output :**

```
{{ var1 }}
{{ var2 }}
{{ var3 }}
{{ var4 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

1. If only td element, replace .Descendants() on .Descendants("td")

   ```
   var placeHolders = mydoc
               .Descendants("td")
               .Where(d => _placeholderRegex.IsMatch((string)d))
               .Select(x => (string)x);
   ```

Link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eoDVWH

2. Or, check the existence of child elements:

   ```
   var placeHolders = mydoc
               .Descendants()
               .Where(d => !d.HasElements && _placeholderRegex.IsMatch((string)d))
               .Select(x => (string)x);
   ```

Link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FEwSf3

Answer (score 0):

You can add `!d.Elements().Any()` to your predicate to get only elements that don't have any children:

```
var placeHolders = _template
    .Descendants()
    .Where(d => !d.Elements().Any() && _placeholderRegex.IsMatch((string)d))
    .ToList();
```